# Solving Avro Schema Problems

Tags: schema, avro

Is there any way of getting useful information about avro schema problems?

I am trying to make the following work

`{
  "namespace": "format.data.something",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "data",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "generator",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "mapping",
      "type": {
        "name": "mappingItemSequence",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "name": "item",
          "type": {
            "name": "mappingItem",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "content",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "tokenOutput",
                "type": {
                  "name": "token",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              {
                "name": "inputTokens",
                "type": {
                  "name": "tokensSequence",
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "name": "tokenInput",
                    "type": {
                      "name": "token",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}`

and I receive a quite cryptic message from maven:

`Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:schema failed: No type: {"name":"item","type":{"name":"mappingItem","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"content","type":"string"},{"name":"tokenOutput","type":{"name":"token","type":"string"}},{"name":"inputTokens","type":{"name":"tokensSequence","type":"array","items":{"name":"tokenInput","type":{"name":"token","type":"string"}}}}]}}`

I am using apache avro 1.8.2 and I am trying to compile to java with maven.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is essentially that you are adding extra information to your array type declaration. The attribute `name` is not required as part of your array definition type (documentation[here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Arrays)).

The following schema should work for you

```
{
  "namespace": "format.data.something",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "data",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "generator",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "mapping",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "name": "mappingItem",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "content",
                "type": "string"
              },
              {
                "name": "tokenOutput",
                "type": {
                  "name": "token",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              {
                  "name": "tokensSequence",
                  "type": { "type":"array",  "items": "string"}

              }
            ]

        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your post, hlagos. Your solution works.

Comment: no @gamliel, if that is the case you can vote so other are aware of that.

Comment: Hi @hlagos. I don't have enough reputation to vote, yet, so I thought I should thank you with a message